# How to close frame from other class that inside this frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have frame, in this frame I have a `JTable` that have button inside, this button have class with `ActionListener` and so on and I need to close this frame after pressing this button. How do this?

Code example:

```
public class Frame2 extends JFrame{   
public  Frame2() {
   JTable table = new JTable(model);
   //...
   table.getColumn("change").setCellEditor(new ButtonCellEditor());
}

public static class ButtonCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor{
    public ButtonCellEditor() {
        editor = new JButton();
        editor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              //do something here
              setVisible(false); //not working, I NEED HERE TO CLOSE THIS FRAME
        });
     }}}
```

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Why does it make sense to have a button in the table that can close the window?

Comment: i am not sure why do you want the specific behavior .. but in order to hide frame you need to call setVisible on frame object

Comment: this button open other Frame and i need to close this frame when other is openning @AndrewThompson

Comment: Bffn, read or re-read @AndrewThompson's link as you obviously are not getting it.

Comment: *"this button open other Frame"* This probably means it should be one frame with a `CardLayout`, or the second frame should be a modal `JDialog` (while the `JFrame` stays open behind it). Read the thread posted in my 1st comment for many ideas. Using 2 or more frames is not a solution here.